# CountWord using spark on cluster azure

Tags: java, scala, azure, apache-spark, sbt

I need to ask some questions of Azure . I want to know how to pass a .jar file into the cluster so that you can launch from the command line cluster azure.

I would also like to know if the code I wrote is correct in scala and especially if it is the right way to go to get the files from the blob using the `wasb://` function .

```
import scala.io.Source
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val textFile = 
      spark.textFile("wasb://blob@storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/prova.txt")
    val counts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
                   .map(word => (word, 1))
                   .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    counts.saveAsTextFile("wasb://blob@storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/provaoutput.txt")
  }
}
```

And last question for launch the program this is the correct code:

```
C:\apps\dist\spark-1.2.0\bin\spark-submit --class "SimpleApp" --master local target/scala-2.10/simpleapp_2.10-1.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question, I think you want to know how to remote access the Spark Cluster on HDInsight.

When you create a spark cluster on HDInsight, you need to enable Remote Desktop, please see below.

[image]

Then you can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-administer-use-management-portal/#rdp to connect to HDInsight clusters using RDP.

And run your spark job like run mapreduce by following the doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-use-mapreduce-remote-desktop/.

[image]

However, there is a simple way to run scala script using a Zeppelin notebool on Azure HDInsight, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-apache-spark-zeppelin-notebook-jupyter-spark-sql/#zeppelin to see more details. Please see the picture below.

[image]